# Entity Framework Many-to-Many Insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three tables.  Named: Merchants, MerchantNumberX, Numbers (numbers is used by many other entities -- this is just one example).

The Merchants table looks like:

```
MerchantGuid, MerchantName
```

The Numbers table looks like:

```
NumberGuid, PhoneNumber
```

The Xref table looks like:

```
MerchantGuid, NumberGuid
```

I know in entity framework I can do this:

```
var newNumber = new Number { NumberGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), PhoneNumber = "55555555555" };
Merchants.Numbers.Add(newNumber);
```

And this will insert the relationship into the Xref table between the two table entities.
However, is there any other way to "relate" these tables together WITHOUT having a Merchant object?

For instance:

```
 var newNumber = new Number { NumberGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), PhoneNumber = "4444444444" };
 newNumber.MerchantGuid = alreadyKnownMerchantGuid;  // This is not available, by the way, just an example of something we are looking for in a many-to-many relationship.
```

However, newNumber gives me a "Merchants" property that just recursively repeats itself.

We are in the process of rewriting a lot of code and wondering if there is a quick way to make this relationship without having to make a call to the database to get a Merchant object since we already have the valid MerchantGuid.

Anyone help with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, is there any other way to "relate" these tables together
>   WITHOUT having a Merchant object?

No. Many-to-many relationships with EF are independent associations, that means, there is no foreign key property available in your model. You need to manipulate relationships using the two collections. That's the only way.

But, see next point...

> ... if there is a quick way to make this relationship without having to
>   make a call to the database to get a Merchant object since we already
>   have the valid MerchantGuid.

To create the relationship you don't need to load the existing `Merchant` entity from the database. You can create a "stub" entity with the key property set to the valid `MerchantGuid` and then attach it to the context. For EF this is an entity in state `Unchanged` that behaves as if it had been loaded from the database:

```
var newNumber = new Number {
    NumberGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), PhoneNumber = "55555555555" };

var merchant = new Merchant {
    MerchantGuid = alreadyKnownMerchantGuid, Numbers = new HashSet<Number>() };
context.Merchants.Attach(merchant);

merchant.Numbers.Add(newNumber);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Here is no database query involved. `SaveChanges` will create a new `Number` record and a new relationship record in the join table.

Comment: I had found the solution last night, but +1 and accept as the solution I came up with as well! :)